# Find .NET Recognizable Guids in a String

Tags: c#, .net, regex, guid

I am looking for a way to find a Guid within a string that is in a .NET recognizable pattern.

There are a few regex's available in this [popular library](http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=guid&c=-1&m=5&ps=100), but I can't find one that works for all of the possible Guids outlined here in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx).

For example, lets say I have a string like this:

> ACTIVITY: "{0xCA761232, 0xED42, 0x11CE, {0xBA, 0xCD, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x57, 0xB2, 0x23}}", Time:09:09:09:09

This should return:

> {0xCA761232, 0xED42, 0x11CE, {0xBA, 0xCD, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x57, 0xB2, 0x23}}

Another example could be:

> Random string CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223 random string

This should return:

> CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223

Any ideas on how to approach this? Is regular expressions the way to go here?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the `{` and `}}` as delimiters for `string.Split`?

Comment: The input string could be something like "random string <proper Guid> random string". It doesn't necessarily have to have braces

Comment: Well, without more examples of representative strings we can't really give you a good solution. What _is_ and _isn't_ expected around the GUID?

Comment: just added one more example. Thanks Oded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Solution is:*

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    string input = "Random string CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223 random string";
    Match match = Regex.Match(input,
      @"((?:(?:\s*\{*\s*(?:0x[\dA-F]+)\}*\,?)+)|(?<![a-f\d])[a-f\d]{32}(?![a-f\d])|" +
      @"(?:\{\(|)(?<![A-F\d])[A-F\d]{8}(?:\-[A-F\d]{4}){3}\-[A-F\d]{12}(?![A-F\d])(?:\}|\)|))");
    if (match.Success)
    {
      string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
      Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("NO MATCH");
    }
  }
}
```

*See and test this code [here](http://ideone.com/sibn7).*

Comment: Incorrect. Note the two separate capture groups and missing final `}`. - http://i.imgur.com/wkNpv.png

Comment: You modified your post after I posted the screenshot. Note the pattern in my screenshot is the original, unedited pattern.

Comment: @SpikeX - I didn't modified capture groups - check that... There is just one.

Comment: Thanks for the effort here, but the goal is to match any .NET recongible Guid. See the OP for the link to the msdn article that has some examples.

Comment: I tried to test this out and I get "[x-y] range in reverse order." when all of the ranges look correct. I tested this using http://www.regexlib.com

Comment: @MohammedAli - I have updated the answer with new code. I have tested in and it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(\{0x[0-9A-F]{8}, 0x[0-9A-F]{4}, 0x[0-9A-F]{4}, \{(?:0x[0-9A-F]{2}, ){7}0x[0-9A-F]{2}\}\})
```

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort here, but the goal is to match any .NET recongible Guid. See the OP for the link to the msdn article that has some examples.